# Accessing and Saving model objects directly without using serializers in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have created an api endpoint for one of my resources called "creative"  . However I needed to have an action to implement pause and start of this resource (to change the field called status) . Hence I created a @detail_route() for the above actions .

What am I trying to achieve: I need to update a field of this particular resource(model) Creative as well as a field of another model  whose foreign key is this model.

I am calling a custom function toggleAdGroupState inside this @detail_route() method where I directly work on the django models rather than using the serializers. Is this allowed ? Is this a proper way of implementing what i need to do ?

```
class CreativeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Creative
        fields = ('__all__')

@detail_route(methods=['post','get','put'])
    def startcreative(self, request, pk=None):
        try:                
            creative_object= self.get_object()
            creative_object.active_status=Creative._STATUS_ACTIVE
            creative_object.save()              
            toggleAdGroupState(creative_object.id,"active")
        except Exception as e:
            print 'error is ',str(e)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def toggleAdGroupState(creative_id,toggleFlag):     
    adgroup_obj = AdGroup.objects.filter(creative=creative_id)
    for item in adgroup_obj:            
        if(toggleFlag == 'active'):
            item.userActivate()
        else:
            item.userInactivate()
```

djangorestframework is 3.2.2

Comment: Is this an action that you want to take anytime that models active_status is changed? If so, you might be better off using signals or a custom save method on the Creative model.

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @KineticStack,@DhiaTN - 
The user will click on a button that should toggle the active_status field of the model Creative ( and also change a field of another model AdGroup to which this creative belongs to ) . So I have tied this to my detail_route method , where clicking on the button will do a put or post request to the api endpoint - /api/creative/<pk>/startcreative.
Note : The above code achieves what I wanted it do . My Question is whether this is an acceptable way ( accessing the django models directly without the use of serializers) under the REST methodology.

Comment: @ram This is acceptable, but what I was asking is if this is something you want to be able to do outside of this exact situation. For example, in the future, you may want to create another button or some other situation that activates it, so keeping with DRY it would be better to use signals or alter the save method to ALWAYS do this when active status is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe are following these steps

1. user clicks to do post/put request.
2. this request active_status from
3. model creative  Next you want to update Another Model.

You can do like this in view for each method. I have shown for `put`,

```
class View(generics.UpdateAPIView):
 ....
 def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # update creative model
    response = generics.UpdateAPIView.update(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    if response.status == 200: 
      # update_another_model()
```